# Having trouble using a dictionary to write text file?

Tags: python, file, loops, dictionary

```
text = open('samiam.txt', 'r+')
replacement = {" i ": " I ", "-i-": "-I-"}
new_file = open('newfile.txt', 'w')

for line in text:
    for k in replacement.items():
        line.replace(k, v)
        new_file.write(line)


text.close()
new_file.close()
```

I run it, it says `v` isn't defined. If I rewrite it `for k, v` then it doesn't have this error, but then the file doesn't change. The text file is just `sam-i-am`, with the `i`'s all lowercased. I'm trying to uppercase them and rewrite it. But can't quite seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing `for k` to `for k, v` is correct since `dict.items` yields key/value pairs.  The reason your file is not updating is because `str.replace` does not work in-place.  Strings are immutable in Python, so the method always returns a new string.

This means that this line:

```
line.replace(k, v)
```

is effectively a no-op.  To fix the problem, simply reassign `line` to this string so that its value is updated:

```
line = line.replace(k, v)
```

---

Also, the `new_file.write(line)` line should be dedented one level:

```
for line in text:
    for k, v in replacement.items():
        line.replace(k, v)
    new_file.write(line) # <-- moved back one level
```

Otherwise, you will write to the file for each item in the `replacement` dictionary.

---

Finally, you can use a [with-statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) to have your files be closed automatically when you are done:

```
replacement = {" i ": " I ", "-i-": "-I-"}
with open('samiam.txt', 'r+') as text, open('newfile.txt', 'w') as new_file:
    for line in text:
        for k, v in replacement.items():
            line = line.replace(k, v)
        new_file.write(line)
```

Comment: ...When I load up new_file after doing this, I get the string repeated. Example:
"I do not like them, sam-i-am.
I do not like them, sam-I-am."
..any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Because it's writing it in for loop.Which is why too many times you see that string.

Comment: @Andrea - See my edit.  You had your `write` line over too far.

Answer (score 1):

```
text = open('samiam.txt', 'r+')
replacement = {" i ": " I ", "-i-": "-I-"}
new_file = open('newfile.txt', 'w')

for line in text:
    for k in replacement.keys():
        line=line.replace(k, replacement[k])
    new_file.write(line)


text.close()
new_file.close()
```

This should solve your problem.I can't run it right now , please tell me if you have problems.